# "Overload" class execute method

Tags: python

I already learned that you can't and don't need to overload in Python, but I didn't know how to call it otherwise.

(all pseudo code)

I have a button:

```
myBox = layout.box()
myBox.operator(my_Button.bl_idname, text = "Move it")
```

And want to add a non-obligatory parameter to the execute method:

```
class my_Button(bpy.types.Operator):
   bl_idname = "object.my_button"
   def execute(self, context, calledByButton=True):
```

So I can call the method by using the button, or somewhere in the script:

```
bpy.ops.object.my_button(False)
```

But I get an error on registering it (strangly for the next class)

> ValueError: expected Operator, my_NextButton class "execute" function to
>   have 2 args , found 3

How would I do that correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do this correctly like this:

```
import bpy

class MyButton(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.my_button"
    bl_label = "My Button"
    flag = bpy.props.BoolProperty(default=True)

    def execute(self, context):
        if self.flag:
            print('Called by button')
        else:
            print('Not called by button')

 bpy.utils.register_class(MyButton)

 #usage:
 myBox.operator("object.my_button").flag = True
 bpy.ops.object.my_button(flag=False)
```

Comment: While this seemed correct at first, I don't seem to be able to do this: bpy.ops.object.my_button.flag = True, because the class isn't initialized and of course I'd run bpy.ops.object.my_button() afterwards to have the flag set at runtime.

Comment: You need to call `bpy.ops.object.my_button(flag=False)`, I will add that. Also the class should have bl_label